# Ubuntu 22.04 ntpd client doesn't sync with the NTP server

Tags: 22.04, ntp

I have problem with ntpd.
I need to use ntpd as ntp client to sync consistently update the time against the NTP server. When I do `timedatectl set-ntp true` I receive the error

> failed to set ntp:N NTP not supported

I heard about that ntpd client on ubuntu 22.04 is not supported and not recommended, but I didn't found any document that proved it.

(it's dark network that's not connected to internet, the ntp server is windows server 2022, the windows clients are syncing good with the ntp server, just the ubuntu with the problem.)